# How to delete the same elements in two arrays or lists?And the elements are arrays or lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, numpy

Best solved in python3.
I have tried to use 'remove' to solve it.But 'list.remove()' can't handle this, it doesn't support to operate 'list in list'.
Many thanks!!!

```
input:label = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
      target = [[2, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
output: c = [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Since you are using python, why don't you use sets and intersection function?

Answer (score 2):

```
label = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
target = [[2, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]


c = []
for tar in target:
    if tar in label:
        c.append(tar)

print(c) # output: c = [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `sets` with bitwise `&` operator:

```
import numpy as np 
label = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
target = [[2, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
l = [x for x in set(tuple(a) for a in label)&set(tuple(b) for b in target)]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the membership operator `in` to identify the similar elements in two arrays or lists and then use the `remove` method to remove them,

```
list1= [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
target = [[2, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
delete=list()

for i in list1:
    if i in target:  #in operator checks whether the element is present in target or not
        delete.append(i)
        print(i)

for i in delete:
    list1.remove(i)
    target.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your intended output is the **intersection** of these lists.

Using *Pandas* it is quite easy to generate it:

1. Create a MultiIndex from each source list:

   ```
   iLabel = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(label)
   iTarget = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
   ```

   You may print them to see their content. Each nested list is converted into
   a *tuple* - an item in particular MultiIndex.
2. To compute the intersection of these 2 indices, run:

   ```
   wrk = iLabel.intersection(iTarget).tolist()
   ```

   It is almost what we want - a list of **tuples**:

   ```
   [(3, 3), (2, 2)]
   ```
3. And to get the intended result - a list of **lists**, run:

   ```
   result = [ list(x) for x in wrk ]
   ```

   getting just `[[3, 3], [2, 2]]`.

But if you want to **drop** these common elements from both source lists, run:

```
label2 = iLabel.difference(wrk).tolist()
target2 = iTarget.difference(wrk).tolist()
```

The result is, respectively:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

To turn each of the above results into a list of **lists**, repeat the code shown
in point 3.